# how to have nodejs wait for a function to complete which is written in other javascript file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to use result of a javascript function in nodejs, however as nodejs is async, it is not waiting for the function to complete. Any help on how to have node wait till this function completes will be great.

Code being called:

```
const patientId =  function(patientUUID) {
 var mysql      = require('mysql');
 var connectionF = mysql.createConnection({
      host     : 'localhost',
      user     : 'localuser',
      password : 'localpass',
      database: 'localdb'
        });
   connectionF.connect();
   connectionF.query(patientIDFinderQuery, [patientUUID], function(error,result,fields) {
      return result[0].patient_id; // I am trying to capture this result precisely
    } );
}
```

Calling code:

```
app.post('/pushdata',  function (req, res,next)  {

connection.query(creatorQuery, [login], function(error,result,fields) {
let visit = req.body.visits[0]
let patientUUID = visit.patient
 let patientId =   dbHelper.patientId(patientUUID); // This is where the code is being called
console.log(patientId); // Returns Undefined
}
});
 res.json({'status':'ok'})
  })
```

Comment: Consider using a [callback function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function), or refactoring your code to use [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await)

Comment: Hi @CameronLittle, can you refeactor it a bit so that I can take it from there

Answer (score 1):

```
const patientId =  function(patientUUID) {
  return new Promise (resolve, reject => {
    ... more code
   connectionF.query(patientIDFinderQuery, [patientUUID], function(error,result,fields) {
      resolve(result[0].patient_id);
    } );
  });
}
```

```
...more code
dbHelper.patientId(patientUUID). then (patientId => {
  console.log(patientId)
});
```

Make PatientId method as promise function.

Comment: Throwing error :    ypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined  for dbHelper.patientId(patientUUID).then (patientId => {
  console.log(patientId)
});
}

Comment: Do log before call the patiendId method.